# Core 2 Override IsInRole method to check another field

Tags: asp.net-core, roles

I have an application with multiple Company, and in each Company I can have multiple building.
All ApplicationUsers are related to only one Company, but every ApplicationUser can have specific roles for every building of the company.

I thought to add the id of the building in the ApplicationRole class, and then override the IsInRole method to check if the ApplicationUser have the right role for the specified building.

I searched for days and does not found any solution that match my problem..

Does anyone knows how to handle that kind of role check ?

Comment: what you are looking for is covered by individual claims, to distinct between different company id's

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer ! I know claims but never used them before and i don't see how it can be done. Do you have any example of how i should use it so i can check role and building id together ?

Comment: you will find what you are looking for using google "c# identitiy claims documentation"